# grep, sum and average from large output

Tags: grep, sum, average

I have an output file called filename.mat0 which contains a large list of data points for a number of different variables for a number of different time steps. I want to use something like the grep command to retrieve all the instances for a given variable, i.e. variable_A, then sum the total value associated with variable_A, then take an average. 
The number of time steps is constant so variable_A, variable_B, etc all appear 100 times in my .mat file. 
Please can you suggest the best way to do this?
An example of the output data is:

```
Timestep1 Variable_A 10
Timestep1 Variable_B 20 
Timestep1 Variable_C 30 

Timestep2 Variable_A 40 
Timestep2 Variable_B 50 
Timestep2 Variable_C 60

Timestep3 Variable_A 70 
Timestep3 Variable_B 80 
Timestep3 Variable_C 90
```

Desired output:

```
Variable_A = 40
```

Comment: Please add sample for your output file

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question, paste in the sample data, then select it with the mouse and click the button marked `{}` beside **Bold** and *Italic* in the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Thank you, I've put the data in the original question now

Comment: No, you haven't - re-read the comments and see [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to [this](https://linuxconfig.org/calculate-column-average-using-bash-shell).

`awk` should be able to solve the problem. Check the link for how to use [awk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm).
The below command should be okay for your case, but it is not easy to use if there is many `Variable` .Hope anyone more familiar with `awk` can suggest how to improve.

```
awk '{if ($2 == "Variable_A"){ total += $3; count++ }} END { print "Variable_A = " total/count }' sample.mat > avg_a.txt
```

Above command will do for each row, check if column 2(correspond to `$2`) equals "Variable_A", if yes, sum the value in column 3(correspond to `$3`) and add a count. After processing all rows, print the average to a text file.

### For further question

In order to show multiple variables average in same file, you can make use of array and for loop in AWK. Add elements to `vars` for more variables.

```
awk 'BEGIN {vars[0]="Variable_A"; vars[1]="Variable_B"; vars[2] ="Variable_C" } { for (i in vars) { if ($2 == vars[i]){ total[i] += $3; count[i]++ }}} END { for(i in vars) {print vars[i]" = " total[i]/count[i]}}' sample.mat > avg.txt
```

Comment: Hi, that worked perfectly - thank you. Is there any way to amend this so that if I wanted to record multiple data averages I can do it and have, say,  both Variable_A and Varibale_B printed to the same avg.txt file?

Comment: I've just tried the command for multiple variables and it's returning an error of 'division by zero attempted'. I'm not sure why

Comment: @smdr I found no errors using the sample you provided, what file you are executing with the command?